# loop through api json data react js

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

i konw there are similar question to this but i couldn't find the solution.
i'm trying to loop through this "div" with data coming from django rest api (JSON format)

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/Post');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            posts: data.data[0],
            loading: false
        });
    }

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-6 paddding animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
        <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_2"><img src={image} alt="img"/>
            <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_position_absolute"></div>
            <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_position_absolute_font_2">
                <div class=""><a href="#" class="color_fff"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{date_posted} </a></div>
                <div class=""><a href="single.html" class="fh5co_good_font_2"> {title} </a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

i tried to use "map" but i'm not sure how

```
function renderposts() {
        const postList = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.state.posts.length; i++) {
            let title = `${this.state.posts[i].title}`;
            let image = this.state.posts[i].image;
            let date_posted = this.state.posts[i].date_posted;
            let key = this.state.posts[i].id.value;
            postList.push(<Post        
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-6 paddding animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                    <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_2"><img src={image} alt="img"/>
                        <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_position_absolute"></div>
                        <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_position_absolute_font_2">
                            <div class=""><a href="#" class="color_fff"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{date_posted} </a></div>
                            <div class=""><a href="single.html" class="fh5co_good_font_2"> {title} </a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div></div>
                />);
        }
  
        return postList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this in your render method:

```
{this.state.posts.map((post) => {
            return (
              <div
                class="col-md-6 col-6 paddding animate-box"
                data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
              >
                <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_2">
                  <img src={post.image} alt="img" />
                  <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_position_absolute"></div>
                  <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_position_absolute_font_2">
                    <div class="">
                      <a href="#" class="color_fff">
                        {" "}
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{post.date_posted}{" "}
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                      <a href="single.html" class="fh5co_good_font_2">
                        {" "}
                        {post.title}{" "}
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

here is a codesandbox example using hooks:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-newton-bc3pw?file=/src/App.js:1021-1961)

Comment: i tried your method but i get "TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function"

Comment: never mind it works, just a syntax error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `data.data[0]` is an array of data. In React, when you want to loop through a array of data, always use method that return a clone of your data such as map or filter to avoid problem with immutability. Here's the specific code for your problem:

```
const postList = this.state.posts.map((post) => {
  // Destructuring assignment
  const { title, image, date_posted } = post;
  const key = post.id.value;
  return (
    <div class="row">
      <div
        class="col-md-6 col-6 paddding animate-box"
        data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
      >
        <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_2">
          <img src={image} alt="img" />
          <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_position_absolute"></div>
          <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_position_absolute_font_2">
            <div class="">
              <a href="#" class="color_fff">
                {' '}
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{date_posted}{' '}
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <a href="single.html" class="fh5co_good_font_2">
                {' '}
                {title}{' '}
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```